# Nextjs Image component srcSet attribute

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I want to load different images for mobile viewport. Based on the Next.js doc passing `srcSet` does not work, so how can I do it?

Right now I can do it with CSS display property but I need something like the below:

```js
<Image
   srcSet={{
      '/path/to/image-small.jpg': 320,
      '/path/to/image-medium.jpg': 640,
      '/path/to/image-large.jpg': 1024,
   }}
   src={data.smallImg.url}
   fill={true}
   alt=""
   className="rounded-[10px]"
/>
```

Comment: You've tried custom load?

Answer (score 0):

The `<Image />` component automatically generates your srcSet, but you can use [deviceSizes](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#devicesizes) in your config if you'd like.

If you want to load a different image for mobile, you could use the [picture element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture). It also looks like Vercel [has been working on support](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/25393#discussioncomment-6310618) to get image props and use them in other elements (like `<picture>`).